# Prevent react-native alert dismiss onPress button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a `react-native` Alert as follow. What i would like to achieve is to prevent the alert box dimiss `onPress` and delay alert box dismiss.

How could this be done with [react-native built in Alert component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert)?

I am assuming that there is a built in `preventAlertBoxDismiss()` and `dismissAlert()` function but couldn't find in documentation.

**1) Prevent alert box dismiss onPress button**

```
onPressAskMeLater = () => {
    preventAlertBoxDismiss();
    anyAction();
}
```

**2) Delay alert box dismiss**

```
onPressAskMeLater = () => {
    preventAlertBoxDismiss();
    setTimeOut(3000);
    dismissAlert();
}
```

**Alert code**

```
Alert.alert(
  'Alert Title',
  'My Alert Msg',
  [
    {text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => this.onPressAskMeLater()},
    {text: 'OK'},
  ],
  {cancelable: false},
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the system does not support that method. it belongs to the native UI component. you can use the component to realize the dialog. in that way, you can control the dialog dismiss.

At the same time, you can also use the third library. for example [`react-native-dialog`](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-dialog).

that use it as the following:

```
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showDialog}>
          <Text>Show Dialog</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Dialog.Container visible={this.state.dialogVisible}>
          <Dialog.Title>Account delete</Dialog.Title>
          <Dialog.Description>
            Do you want to delete this account? You cannot undo this action.
          </Dialog.Description>
          <Dialog.Button label="Cancel" onPress={this.handleCancel} />
          <Dialog.Button label="Delete" onPress={this.handleDelete} />
        </Dialog.Container>
      </View>
....
showDialog = () => {
    preventAlertBoxDismiss();
    setTimeOut(3000);
    dismissAlert();
    this.setState({ dialogVisible: true });
  };
```

in the `showDialog` method, you can delay the dialog dismiss. because it show and dismiss controled by your own state.